# Difference between native.WebView and native.NewWebView?

Tags: coronasdk

There are 2 web views API in **Corona SDK**, for displaying website within the App which uses the SDK. From the documentation, I know that `NewWebView` supports loading local web pages, but have quite a lot of known issues ( such as unable to roate in Android, cannot fire `loaded` event in iOS , etc ). Besides that, if I just want to load a simple web page ( CSS, images & texts only ) online ( on remote web server ), which library should I use ?

Note: the App will support iOS & Android OS

Documentation:

- [native.WebView](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/WebView/index.html)
- [native.NewWebView](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/native/newWebView.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the docs for native.WebView describes the object returned by calling native.newWebView().  They are in fact the same.  One doc describes calling newWebView to create the webView, the other describes what you can do with the webView.